# Error 9 Out of range .Sheets(i)

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel, ms-access-2007

Hey everyone i've been trying to find a solution to my error but i can't find a similar example on the net to resolve this. I have a variable (i) set to 3 when it enters the loop and then enters the first if statement it runs fine, the file is copied and inserted into sheet 3 however once its incremented to 4 and enters the second if statement i get an error 9 on

```
      Set wks4 = wkb.Sheets(i)
```

this is the somewhat of the complete code below, hope you guys can help me out .

```
Set Excel_App = New EXCEL.Application
Excel_App.Visible = False
Set wkb = EXCEL.Workbooks.Add
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1) 'want first sheet

With wks
    ......
    'extra code involing input to sheet 1 
End With


    Dim wkb2 As EXCEL.Workbook
    Set wkb2 = EXCEL.Application.Workbooks.Open(strDir & "\DETAILS.xlsx")

        wkb2.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Set wks2 = wkb.Sheets(2)
        With wks2
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        End With
        wkb2.Close

i = 3
      Do While Not rstTypes.EOF

            If rstTypes![TYPE] Like "GROUPED" Then
                    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "EXCEL_CBD_CAP_CR", acFormatXLS, strDir & "\SAMEDAY_NEXTDAY_FUTURE.xls", 0
                    Dim wkb3 As EXCEL.Workbook
                    Set wkb3 = EXCEL.Application.Workbooks.Open(strDir & "\SAMEDAY_NEXTDAY_FUTURE.xls")

                    wkb3.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Set wks3 = wkb.Sheets(i)
                    With wks3
                        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                    End With
                    wkb3.Close                   
                    i = i + 1
            End If

            If rstTypes![TYPE] Like "GROUPED2" Then
                DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "EXCEL_ND/FUT_CAP_CR", acFormatXLS, strDir & "\NEXTDAY_FUTURE.xls", 0
                    Dim wkb4 As EXCEL.Workbook
                    Set wkb4 = EXCEL.Application.Workbooks.Open(strDir & "\NEXTDAY_FUTURE.xls")


                    wkb4.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Set wks4 = wkb.Sheets(i)
                    With wks4
                        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                    End With
                    wkb4.Close
                    Kill (strDir & "\NEXTDAY_FUTURE.xls")

                    i = i + 1
            End If
            rstTypes.MoveNext
 Loop
```

Comment: First, REALLY STUPID question that has to be asked... Did you declare wks4 in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have a 4th worksheet. Based upon your code, I assume you want the sheet to exist, so you'll need to add the sheet at runtime. You should wrap both of your worksheet settings for wks3 and wks4 in logic like the following:

```
if wkb.Sheets.Count < i then
   Set wks3 = wkb.sheets.add
end if
```

And then later

```
if wkb.Sheets.Count < i then
   Set wks4 = wkb.sheets.add
end if
```

Answer (score 2):

it means that the i-th sheet doesnt exist, check this every time you want to interact with a sheet with a strategically placed:

`If i > ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count then Exit Do`

Answer (score 0):

Also remember the first sheet will be sheet **1** unlike arrays.